# Replace HP Smart Array RAID Controller with newer generation controller (e.g. 410 -> 420)

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have got a faulty P410 Smart Array Controller in my G6 ProLiant, so I decided to replace it. Since I want more flexibility, I choose not to replace it with just another P410, but the succeeding P420 (much of the SAAP-functionality comes with it at no further licensing cost).

Apart from the P420 being a PCIe 3.0 card, whereas the P410 and my server only provide PCIe 2.0, are there any other incompatiblities that might arise?

I've read a [statement by HP](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Replacing-HP-P410-with-P420-and-keeping-the-data/td-p/6735565#.XYSxe2_VJPY) that it should be technically possible, but can anybody confirm this from his/her own business experience?

Comment: You should have specified your server model in the initial post.

Answer (score 3):

The P420 add-in card will probably work...

But it's better to go to a Gen8 server today, if possible.

ProLiant G6 severs are circa 2009. How much is reasonable to invest in a 10 year-old server?

None of the SAAP features are really crucial. And if you just want to keep your old server afloat, get another age-appropriate Smart Array P410.

By the way, since the RAID controller on the G6 systems is embedded on the system board, the failure of the controller is a *really* good indicator that the hardware is near the end of its life. RAID controller failures are uncommon. Embedded controller failures usually require a new system board.

Edit: You say that you already have an add-in P410 RAID controller. Why aren't you using the embedded motherboard Smart Array P410i controller?

Comment: Just a brief correction - the P410 is a standalone PCIe-expansion card. SA Controllers embedded onto the system board are usually designated by an "i" (**i**ntegrated) like a P410i. Nevertheless thank you :)

Comment: Why aren’t you using the embedded RAID controller? It should be present on that system.

Comment: If a ten-year-old server is still running and meeting the OP's needs, is there a reason to replace it?  Computer performance over the past 10 years has *not* seen the spectacular growth of any prior decade.

Comment: To reiterate Mark's point, the best home desktop I've ever had I bought in 2011 and while there is a price discrepancy with newer comparisons I'm making, it performs on par with anything I've had since (for all practical applications I need - not gaming or heavy graphical work). Biggest changes are almost exclusively in efficiency. P.S. I'm excluding 20+ core processors as an advancement because very little software can make use of them effectively.

Comment: @Mark There's operational risk in continuing to use a system of this age. I know because I sold and installed hundreds of this specific server model and understand its common modes of failure. Components are failing... It's absolutely reasonable to assess whether it makes sense to invest more into the old solution.

Comment: @ewwhite It's a SE326M1 (which is basically a customized version of an DL180 G6, but with iLO2 onboard and 25 SFF trays). This specific version, made for SAP and other big companies afaik, really has no integrated controller.

Comment: Oh, DL180's are vastly different than the DL300-series in the G6 variant. For this hardware, you can use any controller you wish provided the backplane connectors are compatible (SAS SFF-8087). This model really isn't a traditional ProLiant, and has proven to be far more reliable than the DL300-series of the same generation. Disregard what I said about system board.